# Functional analysis: Rudin 7.6

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

Could someone give me guidance for the proof of the following problem?

> For $n=1,2,3,...$ and $x$ is a real number, put
>
> $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+n x^2}$
>
> Show that ${f_n(x)}$ converges uniformly to a function $f$.

It is a problem from Baby Rudin chapter 7.

The proof for this problem, which is provided from Roger Cookes solution manual (https://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/67009/rudin%20ch%207.pdf?sequence=5&isAllowed=y) says,

> From Schwartz inequality,
>
> $\mid f_n(x)\mid \leq \frac{\mid x\mid}{\sqrt{2}n\mid x\mid} \mid$

How does he do this manipulation?

I can only get

$\mid f_n(x)\mid^2\leq \frac{\mid x\mid^2}{\mid 1+n x\mid^2}$.

From the Schwartz inequality.

Any comments would be very appreciated!

Comment: People saying they used the Schwartz inequality when it's totally unclear how is a real pet peeve of mine.

Comment: AM-GM : $1+nx^2 \ge 2\sqrt{1\cdot nx^2}$.

Comment: Jake Mirra how is this? Isn't finding a upper bound by some inequality theorem a good argument? I'm sort of new in mathematics so I'd love to hear any comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use $AM-GM$, this means $$1+nx^2\geq2\sqrt{n}|x|$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!